# Show/Hide multiple targets of (class/id) with only same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show, show-hide

I'm trying to get a single `class` name that appears many many times in a page to show/hide when toggled. Several scripts I used only work on one target. I need one toggle to target all the items listed under one `class` or `id` simultaneously without creating unique identifiers for each one.
[Here is a sample of my issue.](http://jsbin.com/ronewerino/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Your sample **has** to be in question itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click on the "hide button", steps 2,5,7,9,10 will toggle and it is using the same class selector "hide"

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
                $("#button").click(function (){
                   $('.hide').toggle(); 
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">hide</button>
        <ul>
            <li>Step 1</li>
            <li class="hide">Step 2(will get hide)</li>
            <li>Step 3</li>
            <li>Step 4</li>
            <li class="hide">Step 5(will get hide)</li>
            <li>Step 6</li>
            <li class="hide">Step 7(will get hide)</li>
            <li>Step 8</li>
            <li class="hide">Step 9(will get hide)</li>
            <li class="hide">Step 10(will get hide)</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Pons! My results are Great.
[Click to see my code.](http://jsbin.com/xodini/edit?html,js,output)
I have a floating menu bar that I will put the buttons in. I'll add that code later when I get time.
Thanks again!